# React Native (Flatlist)

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Is there any way to set when the flatlist should become scrollable, I don't want my list items to get all the way to the bottom of the screen. I want it to start scrolling at a certain point in the array.

Comment: Are you just asking how to set the `height` of the `FlatList`?

Comment: I suppose I am, yes. How do I do that?

Comment: style={{height: 300}}

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was overthinking it. I just used maxHeight